# In CSS, how do you make the background color static, so when you scroll, there is no gradient change?

Tags: html, css, background, tags, background-color

I want to set up the background color and gradient of the page so that it's fixed. When i scroll down, the color gradient changes with the scroll.

Top of page https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvDT8.png
Bottom of page https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8F7F.png

How do you set it up so that when you scroll down, the backround color (INSIDE THE RED BOXES) doesent change like in the picture, but it stays the same. With a shorter gradient distance, but fixed when scrolling.

Thank you very much!

edit:

CSS code

```
html {

    background: #ffffff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(252, 219, 174) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    background: rgba(250, 255, 238, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.06);
    color: #545454;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    padding: 2em 2em 4em;
}
```

Comment: a `position:fixed` may help you?

Comment: Please show your HTML and CSS and how you did the gradient background

Comment: `html, body { background-color: red }`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the background with `background-image`, you can use `background-attachment: fixed`. If needed, you can also control the position with `background-position` and the size with `background-size`

```
html {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```